# Encrypt filenames in WinRar SFX

Tags: installation, encryption, deployment, rar, self-extracting

I would like to encrypt the

1. Filenames
2. Codes

in WinRAR SFX.

[image: WinRAR screenshot]

Question: Is it possible to encrypt the above mentioned, but letting the user to run / extract without a password?

Comment: What do you mean by an encrypted archive that can be decrypted without a password (AFAIK, encryption occurs using a password)? If you only want to obfuscate the filenames, just rename them to something illegible. Or you can simply encrypt the archive and put the password in the filename. Or you can build a complex system that extracts an encrypted archive and decrypts it using a hard-coded password automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Question: It is possible to encrypt the above mentioned, but letting the user to run / extract without a password?

Of course not! Why would you need to set a password if it is not going to be used to secure the files!

Comment: i just wanted to encrypt the filenames and code, but let the user execute / extract the archive without seeing the contents of the archive